# Updating Core Data +iCloud model with the next App version

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, upgrade, icloud

I have to work on the next version of an Application that uses Core Data and iCloud. 
iCloud has been activated in the current version using the most "modern" way:

```
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:@"data_cfg"
                                                             URL:storeURL
                                                         options:@{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:@"theStore"}
                                                           error:&error])
```

Now I need to update the store structure adding new entities, relationship and so on...

I'm totally stuck because I don't know which is the better way to update a model knowing that iCloud is synchronised with users data.

Which is the best way to perform an update like that? What should I be aware of and what I should pay attention for the most? How to migrate the current data?

Answer (score 5):

Updating a model when using iCloud is the same as when not using iCloud-- with the sole exception that your changes *must* be ones that work with automatic lightweight migration. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) describes the requirements for this kind of migration in detail. The basic steps are:

1. Create a new version of the data model, and make this version "current". (You must keep the old model around, so now you'll have two, but only one is current).
2. Make your model changes in the new version.
3. Add `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` to your options dictionary in the code above, using `@YES` as the value for both.

Now when you launch the app, Core Data will compare the old and new versions of the model and (assuming your changes work for automatic lightweight migration) modify the persistent store to use the new version.

Keep in mind that iCloud syncing only works between devices that use the same version of the data model. If a user upgrades your app on one device but not another that they use, syncing will stop until they upgrade the app on other device as well.

Answer (score 5):

iCloud Backup doesn't matter, by the way here is solution for installing new sqlite model.
If the data inside the Application can be recreated/downloaded from server, there is a great solution.
You don't need to setup migration stack, there is a very quick solution. The trick is to delete the old sqlite database and create a new one.

Here is the code that I used on my application update.
You need to add this in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourDatabase.sqlite"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [self managedObjectModel];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: managedObjectModel];

    // Check if we already have a persistent store
    if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [storeURL path]] ) {
        NSDictionary *existingPersistentStoreMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType: NSSQLiteStoreType URL: storeURL error: &error];
        if ( !existingPersistentStoreMetadata ) {
            // Something *really* bad has happened to the persistent store
            //[NSException raise: NSInternalInconsistencyException format: @"Failed to read metadata for persistent store %@: %@", storeURL, error];
            NSLog(@"Failed to read metadata for persistent store %@: %@", storeURL, error);
        }

        if ( ![managedObjectModel isConfiguration: nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata: existingPersistentStoreMetadata] ) {
            if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL: storeURL error: &error] )
                NSLog(@"*** Could not delete persistent store, %@", error);
        } // else the existing persistent store is compatible with the current model - nice!
    } // else no database file yet

    [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:storeURL
                                                    options:nil
                                                      error:&error];
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

This code covers issues

- if existing database is old one, than deleting and setting up new one.
- if there is no database yet (user download only the newest version) than creating new database.
- if existing database is compatible with new one, just using that.

Just change the @"YourDatabase.sqlite" to your sqliteDB filename and it will work fine.

If your'e data can't be recreated (synced from server), than You need to setup migration stack
here is link to Apple's guide https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/CoreDataVersioning.pdf